# document.getElementById not working for <a> tag

Tags: javascript, html, class, getelementbyid

I'm very new to js so kindly help me with this.

I am trying to add a class to a  tag using onClick.

The code is as shown below:

```
<a class="gkvSprite" href="#" id="abc" onClick="showhide('1')">Click 1</a>
<a class="gkvSprite" href="#" id="def" onClick="showhide('2')">Click 2</a>
<a class="gkvSprite" href="#" id="hij" onClick="showhide('3')">Click 3</a>
```

Now when i click i need to add a class called "selected" for the one i select.
I tried using setAttribute and add class of jquery as well but was not successful

When i alert the document.getelementbyId(123) it gives out the link.

Can someone kindly help me?

Thanks in Advance
Alloi

Comment: @Kartik try adding item_number it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the code for `showhide` there is no way to see exactly what you're doing wrong. Since you mention jQuery, here is how to do what you describe with it:

```
$('.gkvSprite').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

It's also worth noting that it's invalid to start an ID with a number.

Comment: document.getElementById('abc').setattribute("className", "some_class_name"); 

I am executing the above code.

When i alert document.getElementById('abc') it shows http://localhost/gkv/# and not as an object.

Comment: The function is `setAttribute` and it's case sensitive. With that change, your code works for me. Also note that when you use `alert`, you are shown the "value" of the link element. If you use `console.log` instead, which you should always be doing for debugging, you'll see that it's actually the entire DOM element.

Answer (score 7):

`id` should begin with an alphabet.

[Official specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2)

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

---

Also,

```
var element = document.getElementById('id');
element.className += "newClass";
```

The `showhide()` should do something like above.

Comment: i changed that to alphabets but, its still the same result